# Получить Request из PUT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Создаю метод `PUT`, делаю контроллер и пытаюсь откорректировать данные которые находятся в базе но на запрос `PUT` я получаю `Bad Request, Required request body is missing`. Помогите разобраться в чем ошибка

```
@PutMapping(value = "api/names/{username}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updatePerson(@RequestBody Person person, @PathVariable String username){
    Optional<Person> currentPerson = personRepository.findById(username);
    person.setOld(person.getOld());
    person.setEmail(person.getEmail());
    person.setPassword(person.getPassword());
    personRepository.save(person);
    return new ResponseEntity<Person>(person, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Проверьте наличие тела в http запросе. Как вы его отправляете?

Comment: @talex, вот такой запрос пытаюсь отправить `http://localhost:8080/api/names/Monstr -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "Email": "gardv@mail.ru", "old":"12", "password":"2345"}'`

Comment: Вроде выглядит нормально. В серверном логе ошибок нет?

Comment: @talex, после неудачных запросов в логе появляется `Failed to read HTTP message:org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:`

Comment: И больше ничего? Может дебаг логи попробовать включить. Похоже что тело приходит но не парсится.

Comment: @talex, и дебагер тоже ничего не показывает, ошибка только такая, как выше описал

Comment: @talex, нашел вот такую вот ошибку `JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of "com.mongodb.Person" (although at least one Creator exists)`

Comment: Добавьте код `Person` к вопросу. Возможно с ним что-то не так.

Comment: @talex, забыл создать пустой конструктор, в этом была причина. Спасибо вам большое за старание и уделенное время

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он говорит, что у вас пустое тело запроса. Проверте отправляете ли вы его, должно быть что то вроде этого

```
{old:10, email:xxx@zz.ru, password:1234}
```

И ваш код не будет работать правильно, потому что вместо редактирования существующей person, будет создана новая

```
@PutMapping(value = "api/names/{username}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updatePerson(@RequestBody Person person, @PathVariable String username){
    Person currentPerson = personRepository.findById(username).orElseThrow(()->new NotFoundException("Person not found"));
    currentPerson.setOld(person.getOld());
    currentPerson.setEmail(person.getEmail());
    currentPerson.setPassword(person.getPassword());
    return new ResponseEntity<Person>(personRepository.save(currentPerson), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

так будет правильнее

Comment: подскажите как правильно делать запрос с контентом, пример своего оставил выше

Comment: Нашел ошибку, забыл создать пустой конструктор